# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'a.ProjectRec = System.Data.DataRowView a.SystemRec = 1'

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I am trying to get the value of selected item for my combobox which it loads the data from my database.

this is how i define the code. but I can't find what I'm missing. I get this error when i try to run the program.

```
private void LoadSchematicIndex()
{
   string sql;
      if (p2pMode == p2p.Trace)
         sql = string.Format("SELECT a.RecNo, a.FileName, 
         a.Title as [Trace Schematic Title] FROM Files a WHERE 
         a.ProjectRec = {0} AND a.SystemRec = {1} ORDER BY a.Title",
         (string)cbModel.SelectedValue, (int)systemMode);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably your syntax error is due to the lack of single quote around the value for ProjectRec.
You should have written something like:

```
 "FROM Files a WHERE a.ProjectRec = '{0}' AND a.SystemRec = {1} ORDER BY a.Title"
```

But you should never use any form of string concatenation when building sql commands.
If you do, you expose your code to [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and you have to deal with parsing problems.

For example, strings should be enclosed in single quotations and, if a string value contains a single quote, you need to double it.

It is far better to use a parameterized query

```
    sql = "SELECT a.RecNo, a.FileName, a.Title as [Trace Schematic Title] " + 
          "FROM Files a WHERE a.ProjectRec = @prec AND a.SystemRec = @srec ORDER BY a.Title";
```

then, in your command or adapter

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prec", cbModel.SelectedValue.ToString());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@srec, systemMode);
```

Comment: Great answer as always, Steve - +1.